# Why should makefiles have an "install" target?

Tags: build-system, cmake, make, install

Coming from the world of C and C++, most build system have an `install` target, notably Makefiles (where it is [recommended by GNU](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Standard-Targets.html) for example) or [CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html). This target copies the runtime files (executables, libraries, ...) in the operating system (for example, in `C:\Program Files\` on Windows).

This feels really hacky, since for me **it is not the responsibility of the build system to install programs** (which is actually the responsibility of the operating system / package manager). It also means the build system or build script must know the organization of installed programs, *with environment variables, registry variables, symlinks, permissions, etc.*

At best, build systems should have a `release` target that will output an installable program (for example `.deb` or `.msi`), and then kindly ask the operating system to install that program. It would also allow the user to uninstall without having to type `make uninstall`.

So, my question: **why do build system usually recommend having an `install` target?**

Comment: Your arguing that "make install" does not fall within the responsibility of a build system, but the much more involved and platform specific responsibility of creating an installable package does.

Comment: @pmf Well, I think modifying the system is way outside the build system responsabilities... For example, there is a high risk of breaking things when a package is installed via `make install` but `apt` is not aware of it

Comment: @Synxis It's whoever runs make install that has the responsibility for not breaking anything, by providing install destinations and ensuring there are no conflicts. Given those, it's the build systems responsibility to assemble a working program on the system.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that installing programs is the responsibility of the OS?  It may be the case that a package manager is useful for common, widely-used programs (what might be thought of as "commercial" software in a different OS), but that's only a fraction of programs, running a gamut from specialized research software to user-developed code.  If I write a small utility (as I often do) or make ongoing changes to things I develop, am I really going to use a package manager?

Comment: If you can create a deb/rpm you can also install a package according to those specs. You could implement `make install` by `make deb && apt install ./the_package.deb -y`

Comment: Anyway: sometimes you want to install a n application that is **not** handled by the OS/package manager (because it has dependencies that would cause conflicts impossible to resolve using the package manager etc). `make install` usually installs under `/usr/local` (or even `/opt`) which are directories not handled by the "core OS/package management system". No idea whether Windows has some similar convention though.

Comment: "This feels really hacky."  Well, what did you expect from the world of C/C++? ;-)

Comment: Note that `make install` makes no sense when we talk about cross-compiling

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen it does with `DESTDIR`.

Answer (score 24):

Many build scripts or Makefiles have an installation target because they were created before package managers existed, and because even today lots of systems don't have package managers. Plus, there are systems where `make install` actually *is* the preferred way of managing packages.

Comment: I'm curious about systems where `make install` is preferred. Apart from that, I meant *program manager* when I said that makefiles should create installable packages. I think almost all OS come with a way of managing the installed programs ? For example, Windows has no package manager (apart from the store) but still has a way to manage installed programs (via `.msi` packages for examples)

Comment: @Synxis BSD, Linux, Unix all use makefiles. Whether it's preferred to use them for installation, I don't know, but you often have that ability using `make install`.

Comment: In debian at least it's preferred to use [`checkinstall`](https://debian-administration.org/article/147/Installing_packages_from_source_code_with_checkinstall) over `make install` for two reasons: "You can easily remove the package with one step." and "You can install the resulting package upon multiple machines."
 - as checkinstall builds a .deb and installs it, it uses the package manager...

Comment: @Synxis - There are several linux distributions (often called source distros) where the package manager install programs by downloading a tar file, decompress it then run `make install`

Comment: @AaronHall Correct me if I'm wrong, but I got the impression that a `checkinstall` invocation will actually *use* `make install` and monitor it's actions for package building.

Comment: @Synxis consider a system where the package manager isn't supported by the project's current packaging efforts.  By relying on GNU standards, one can set the install prefix into something under /opt and have a working installation; or, one could figure out which files need to be "where" and package them yourself.  Note that some package managers (RPM) even support installations outside of the package as part of the packaging, to see if the upstream project changed the package file lists, triggering package maintainers to pay attention to the changes.

Answer (score 5):

A `makefile` might have no `install` target, and more importantly, you can have programs which are not even supposed to be installable (e.g. because they should run from their build directory, or because they can run installed anywhere). The `install` target is just a *convention* for usual `makefile`-s.

However, many programs require external resources to be run (for example: fonts, databases, configuration files, etc). And their executable often make some hypothesis about these resources. For example, your `bash` shell would generally read some initialization file from `/etc/bash.bashrc` etc.... These resources are generally in the file system (see [hier(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html) for *conventions* about the file hierarchy) and the default file path is built in your executable.

Try to use [strings(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strings.1.html) on most executables of your system. You'll find out which file paths are known to it.

BTW, for many GNU programs using `autoconf`, you could run `make install DESTDIR=/tmp/destdir/` without being root. Then `/tmp/destdir/` is filled with the files that should be later packaged.

FWIW, I tend to believe that my [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) (GPLv3+ licensed) program (described in my [bismon-chariot-doc.pdf](https://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report) cannot be "installed"; I am not sure to be able to prove that, and I cannot imagine how could I make that program installable.

Comment: DESTDIR or other prefixes are too often forgotten. As soon as external resources such as dynamic libraries are involved, it is not possible to *build* the software without knowing where it will be *installed*. Also great for installing to non-standard locations, e.g `/opt` or into `$HOME`. The only way to avoid different prefixes is to use containers, but that's of course a Linux-specific solution.

Comment: I've seen more than one package that if you tried DESTDIR=/tmp/destdir would not work later when installed to the normal place because DESTDIR was used in path generation.

Comment: @amon: I'm not sure I would characterize containers as Linux-specific.  Linux may be a common target platform for containerization, but [some form of container technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization) exists in most modern operating systems.

Comment: @Joshua It shouldn't, DESTDIR should only be relevant during the install step.

You should be able to do:

    `./configure --prefix="/opt/foo" && make && DESTDIR=/tmp/foo make install`


and be able to relocate the package to `/opt/foo` without any issue.

Answer (score 3):

There are several reasons which come to mind.

- Many package creating software - the [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) build system for example, and IIRC rpm as well - already expect from the building script to "install" the program to some special subdirectory. So it is driven by backward compatibility in both directions.
- A user may want to install the software to a local space, like in the `$HOME` directory. Not all package managers support it.
- There may still be environments which do not have packages.

Comment: I reworded the question a bit, I meant *program manager* when I said that makefiles should create installable packages.

Answer (score 1):

One reason not mentioned is there's a lot of times when you are not using the current version of the software or using a modified version of the software. Trying to create a custom package is not only more work, but it can conflict with currently created and distributed packages. In open source code this happens a lot especially if breaking changes are introduced in future versions you are using.

Let's say you're using the open source project FOO which is currently on version 2.0.1 and you are using version 1.3.0. You don't want to use anything above that because version 2.0.0 is incompatible with what you are currently doing, but there is a single bug fix in 2.0.1 you desperately need. Having the `make install` option let's you install the modified 1.3.0 software without having to worry about creating a package and install it on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Linux distributions generally separate program maintenance from package maintenance. A build system that integrates package generation would force program maintainers to also perform package maintenance.

This is usually a bad idea. Distributions have lots of infrastructure to verify internal consistency, provide binaries for multiple target platforms, perform small alterations to better integrate with the rest of the system and provide a consistent experience for users reporting bugs.

To generate packages directly from a build system, you would have to either integrate or bypass all of this infrastructure. Integrating it would be a lot of work for questionable benefit, and bypassing it would give a worse user experience.

This is one of the "top of the food chain" problems that are typical in multi-party systems. If you have multiple complex systems, there needs to be a clear hierarchy of which system is responsible for coordinating all others.

In the case of software installation management, the package manager is this component, and it will run the package's build system, then take the output through a convenient interface ("files in a directory after an installation step"), generate a package and prepare it for upload to a repository.

The package manager stands in the middle between the build system and the repository here, and is in the best position to integrate well with both.

You may have noticed that there are only few of the JavaScript packages available through `npm` also available through `apt` — this is mainly because the JavaScript people decided that `npm` and the associated repository was going to be the top of their food chain, which made it close to impossible to ship these packages as Debian packages.

With my Debian Developer hat on: if you release open source software, please leave the packaging to distribution maintainers. It saves both you and us a lot of work.

Comment: You've said nothing about why there's an install target, and it seems to me that most of what you've written would apply to it too...

Comment: @curiousdannii, there needs to be *some* interface between build system and package manager, and this happens to be the simplest one, so it won.

Answer (score 1):

Well, application developers are the ones that know where each file should go. They could leave that in documentation, and have package maintainers read that and build a script for each package. Maybe the package maintainers will misinterpret the documentation and will have to debug the script until it works. This is inefficient. It's better for the application developer to write a script to properly install the application he's written.

He could write an install script with an arbitrary name or maybe make it part of the procedure of some other script. However, having a standard install command, `make install` (a convention that predates package managers), it's become really easy to make packages. If you look at the [PKGBUILD template for making Archlinux packages](https://git.archlinux.org/pacman.git/tree/proto/PKGBUILD.proto), you can see that the function that actually packages simply does a `make DESTDIR="$pkgdir/" install`. This probably works for the majority of packages and probably more with a little modification. Thanks to `make` (and the autotools) being standard, packaging is really, really easy.